# Understanding the meaning of a certain boundary condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, boundary-conditions, convection

Given,
$$
-k\frac{\partial T }{ \partial y}=h(T_f-T),
$$
what does this term $$\left.{\partial T \over \partial y}\right|_{y =0}$$ physically describe in the convective boundary condition?

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/198255/

Comment: yes, related but simply this term tell us physically the rate of flux.but i am not sure about my answer that its tell the rate of flux are something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sides to the interface:  the side where the conductive heat transfer is occurring and the side where the convective heat transfer is occurring.  This boundary condition says that the rate of heat conduction toward the interface on the conductive side of the interface is equal to the rate of heat convection away on the convective side of the interface.  In other words, the heat flow is continuous across the interface.  The rate of conduction toward the interface is proportional to the temperature gradient approaching the interface, which is what the left hand side of the equation represents.